# laravel 5.2 Method [validate1] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

My validation fails with this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name'           => ['required'],
            'email'          => ['required', 'email', 'unique:organisers',$organiser->id,'organisers_id'],
            'organiser_logo' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:10000'],
        ]);
```

but it works with this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name'           => ['required'],
            'email'          => ['required', 'email', 'unique:organisers'],
            'organiser_logo' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:10000'],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
'unique:organisers',$organiser->id,'organisers_id'
```

needs to be:

```
'unique:organisers,'.$organiser->id.',organisers_id'
```

or (note the double-quotes):

```
"unique:organisers,{$organiser->id},organisers_id"
```

The `,` means "new array element", the `.` means "add to this string".

Comment: This should be the right answer. Indeed, ```,``` will add a new element to the array, which is not what you want.

Comment: Didn't know you can change to this format. I was too focused on their given format that I didn't bother changing it. Thank you!